# What happens if we use touch command while the file already exists

Tags: touch

I already have a file named `param.txt` with some data on it. If I run 
`touch param.txt` in the same folder will my data get lost?

Answer (score 47):

The contents of the file will not be lost, and it won't even be modified.  The only thing that happens when you run `touch` on an already existing file is that the file's access and modification timestamps are updated to the current time.

This is the primary use for the `touch` utility and this is explained in the `touch` manual (`man touch`).